# Search PostgreSQL column for substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB column that has entries like this:

- "56/45/34"
- "78/34/145"
- "45"
- "" (i.e. NULL)

I want to search for the rows that match a certain number - for example "45" would should return the first and third rows but not the second.

Answer (score 4):

We can try using a regex approach here with word boundaries:

```
select col
from your_table
where col ~* '\y45\y';
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the delimited string to an array and then test the array

```
select *
from the_table
where '45' = any(string_to_array(the_column, '/'))
```